# Validating yaml file by json scheme in monaco editor gives incorrect error

Tags: validation, yaml, monaco-editor

```
monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
        validate: true,
        schemas: \[
    {
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Welcome1",
        "definitions": {
            "Welcome1": {
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "properties": {
                    "inventory": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/Inventory"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "required": \[
                    "inventory"
                \],
                "title": "Welcome1"
            },
            "Inventory": {
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "properties": {
                    "devices": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Devices"
                    },
                    "pollfrequency": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "scopedinventoryobject": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": \[
                    "devices",
                    "pollfrequency",
                    "scopedinventoryobject"
                \],
                "title": "Inventory"
            },
            "Devices": {
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "properties": {
                    "platformtypes": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "required": \[
                    "platformtypes"
                \],
                "title": "Devices"
            }
        }
    }
    
    \]
    });
```

Providing a screenshot for incorrect validation that i have. I haven't found a guide to use a `monaco-yaml` , so I am just trying to validate by json schema that i have for the file. Is it the right way for yaml validation in monaco editor? Or should i implement different approach right here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the exact same problem. From what I understand when we set the schema to: monaco.languages.json.jsonDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions
The schema is only referenced to the json language declared in model.

So, you are even defining the schema, but you are using a different language in the model. (Even so, the print error seems to be referenced to json)

I'm trying to use the package [monaco-yaml](https://github.com/remcohaszing/monaco-yaml) because it seems that it already implements the validation

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ajv library](https://ajv.js.org/) and [JS-yaml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml) for validating yaml files from a json schema. It works well just the problem is as I tried it, it doesn't return the exact line number. It just return the missing fields. You can use it in this way:

```
import Ajv from "ajv"
import JsYaml from 'js-yaml';



function YamlValidation(yamlData?: any) {


const ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true });

  try {
    const jsonData = JsYaml.load(yamlData);
    const valid = ajv.validate(schema, jsonData);

    if (!valid) {
      const errors = ajv.errors;

      if (errors) {
        const validationErrors = errors.map((error: any) => {
          const errorInfo = {
            line: null as number | null,
            column: null as number | null,
            message: error.message || 'Unknown error',
          };

          if (error instanceof JsYaml.YAMLException) {
            errorInfo.line = error.mark.line + 1;
            errorInfo.column = error.mark.column + 1;
          }

          return errorInfo;
        });

        console.log('Validation Errors:', validationErrors);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Valid');
    }

    return true;
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```